# Active Directory with No-IP domain?

Tags: domain, active-directory

Is it possible to configure **Active Directory** to be used with a **No-IP** domain name?

I want my domain like `exemple.no-ip.org` to be used as an Active Directory domain.

So, in clear, if I connect my home PC to the No-IP domain, even if the server is at my work (for exemple), it will work. Like a normal TLD.

Comment: I don't know what you expect to achieve by doing that.  It would make more sense if you wanted to use the same domain name as you do for a website, in which case you will need to know how to configure private and public DNS server in a split-brain configuration.

Comment: You VPN connection address can be different to your domain name, by the way.

Comment: Your idea may be interesting but I don't have 2 IPs, do I need 2 IPs for a domain name? 'Cause I can't have 2 IPs from my ISP...

Comment: No, you need 2 public IP addresses to use DirectAccess, which is not easy to set up.

Comment: Ok, I see... I'll check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess not.  For an AD client to work, it needs a lot more than a single DNS entry.  There are numerous service records that would need to be populated.  On top of that, your firewall would need a lot of open ports to support the client.

You could look into Direct Access with UAG.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd857320.aspx

Comment: He'd need to public IP addresses for DirectAccess, which seems unlikely.